# Options with hierarchical data not selecting

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying run [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/nTYL05qS059rB4hEmXJE?p=preview) sample to select an option from a select with hierarchical data but it's not working.

```
    $scope.options = [
      { id: 1, info: { label: "Item 1" } },
      { id: 2, info: { label: "Item 2" } },
      { id: 3, info: { label: "Item 3" } }
    ];
```

```js
        angular.module("selectOptionsTest", [])
            .controller("SelectOptionsController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {

                $scope.options = [
                  { id: 1, info: { label: "Item 1" } },
                  { id: 2, info: { label: "Item 2" } },
                  { id: 3, info: { label: "Item 3" } }
                ];

                $scope.selectopt = function () {
                    $scope.opt = { id: 1, info: { label: 'Item 1' } };
                };

            }]);
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.1/angular.js">
    </script>
    <div ng-app="selectOptionsTest" ng-controller="SelectOptionsController">
        <select ng-model="opt"
                ng-options="option.id as option.info.label for option in options"></select>
        <input type="button" ng-click="selectopt()" value="select" />
    </div>
```

**Edit 1:**

Here I am adding my code that mostly similar to plunker code.

Controller code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
    .module('app.module')
    .controller('SomeController', SomeController);

    SomeController.$Inject = [
        '$scope'
    ];

    function SomeController(
        $scope
    ) {

        $scope.GetOptions = function () {
            OptionsService.Get().then(function (response) {
                $scope.Options = response.value;
            }, ErrorHandlerService.ShowError);
        };

        $scope.GetOptions();

        $scope.Edit = function (index) {
            $scope.SelectedOption = $scope.Options[index].id;
        };

    }

})();
```

Html code:

```
<select name="Contrato" class="form-control" ng-model="SelectedOption" required autofocus ng-disabled="!IsEditMode"
        ng-options="c.id as c.info.name for c in Options track by c.id">
</select>
```

Options JSON

```
[
    {
      "info":{
        "name":"AAA"
      },"id":1
    },
    {
      "info":{
        "name":"BBB"
      },"id":2
    }
]
```

Comment: That doesn´t make much sense, with having a ng-model in the select, what you select will be on $scope.opt, you don´t need to manually set it on a button click. $scope.opt will always have the index of the selected option (1 indexed)

Comment: @juvian - so what I need to do if I want to select an option manually?

Comment: If you want to change selected from code, it´s as simple as $scope.opt = 3. If you want to let the user select something but only apply changes to another thing when it clicks your button, just add the logic on your onclick method, but don´t set the $scope.opt, just retrieve the object as $scope.options[$scope.opt-1]. If you remove the onclick method, it already works as a normal select should

Comment: @juvian - it works in well plunker but don't know why it does not work in my code.

Comment: @juvian - I did check my html in my case option value is numeric value only (value="1") while in plunker it has added attribute (value="number:2").

Comment: Provide your real example then, because the one you showed works

Comment: @juvian - have added the code and my angularjs version is AngularJS v1.5.0, if it does matter.

Comment: Still don´t understand the usage of Edit, but change in the select c.id as to c as

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116127/discussion-between-ankit-and-juvian).

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the `$scope.opt` model holds the selection. But you are not really using the whole object when you show it. So `$scope.opt` does not contain the whole object, only the `option.id`. So in order for it to work you need to assign an id manually to the model.

```
$scope.selectopt = function () {
   $scope.opt = 1;
};
```

In this case, you assign it `1` and this is the id of the first object in the current options.

Ideally, use a variable instead of hardcoding, like:

```
$scope.selectopt = function () {
  $scope.opt = $scope.options[0].id;
};
```

Comment: In my case options value has numeric value only (value="1") while in plunker it has added attribute.

My Html: <option value="3" label="Item 3">Item 3</option>

Plunker: <option value="number:3" label="Item 3">Item 3</option>

can you help in this?

Comment: Okay, what is your question, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

With ng-model bound to the select, as soon as you change the select option, the model (opt) will update.

You could use the Select button if you want to take the value of "opt" and use it for something else, or save it, etc. but if all you want to do is change it, then just changing the value in the `select` is sufficient.

If you want the entire object set to "opt", then change your select to this:

```
<select ng-model="opt"
            ng-options="option as option.info.label for option in options"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the foll link...it is getting the hierarchy

https://plnkr.co/edit/VQsJBR2lx7zTJxebriZW?p=preview

```
<body>
  <div ng-app="selectOptionsTest" ng-controller="SelectOptionsController">
    <select ng-model="id" ng-options="option.id as option.info.label for option in options"></select>
    <input type="button" ng-click="selectopt()" value="select" />
    <p> Selected:{{opt}}</p>
  </div>
</body>





$scope.selectopt = function() {
          $scope.opt = $scope.options[$scope.id-1];
        };
```